# How to enable VSCode Interactive Editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

Im using Vscode and Gitlens . I want to be able to do an interactive rebase. I have `core.editor=code --wait` set. But when I try and run a rebase I get the text-based editor instead, like so:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: The GUI for interactive rebase seems to be provided by gitlens, not git graph.

Comment: @felix001 Have you had a chance to check the provided solution below?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please check if the **interactive rebase editor** option is **checked** from within the GitLens settings in VS Code:

```
Ctrl + Shift + P > GitLens: Open Settings
```

[image: GitLens Settings]

You should then be able to invoke the interactive rebase editor from both the VS Code command palette, or from the terminal as follows:

```
git -c sequence.editor="code --wait --reuse-window" rebase --interactive <base>
```

*If you're on the VS Code Insiders edition, replace `code` in the above with `code-insiders`.*

Comment: Cannot find this screen / menu. VsCode version 1.67.2 (Ubuntu 18.04). There is only a weird welcome screen "WalkThrough, Quick setup, etc". Maybe it's conflicting with other extensions (git history, git graph)?

Comment: @mcExchange Hmm I don't think other extensions could interfere with each other that way. Wasn't able to verify on Ubuntu, but [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX4Y9.png) is how it looks on my Mac having VS Code 1.72.0.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me. just execute the following command on your terminal

```
git config --global sequence.editor "code --wait --reuse-window"
```

Now execute the following command on VS Code Terminal to get GitLens Interactive editor.

```
git rebase -i <branch_name>
```

Comment: After git rebase -i I now get:                                     
```hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... code --wait --reuse-window: code: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'code --wait --reuse-window'.```

Comment: Did you install Gitlens??

Answer (score -3):

you should use Gitlens vs code extension for this

Comment: I can confirm I am using Git lens :-)